# Excel VBA - Calling individual cells in a defined name

Tags: excel, vba

I have defined a column by the column after it (i.e. Data1 -> Label1, Data2 -> Label2, etc.)  I found I need to add a data field to my form, and it will also be dependent on the currently named column (i.e. Extra1 -> Label 1, etc.).

I can create all new labels, but I would rather have both of the cells be dependent on the same label.  I have played around on a scrap sheet, and cannot make a cell equal to a defined name's cells when there are more than one.  If I only have one, I have no problem:

```
A         B
Data1     Label1
=Label1
```

Will give me Data1 in row two.

```
A         B         C
Data1     Data2     Label1
=Label1
```

Will give me a #VALUE error.

How do I grab an individual cell from a defined name like this?  Is it a range?  Trying to grab it in VBA as Label1.Cells(x, x) give me an error as well.  Am I going to have to make a separate label for the second data column (not ideal).

Thanks,

Comment: `Range("Label1").Cells(x, x)`?

Comment: yes, the defined name is the name of the range now. Use @rdhs 's suggestion in the comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` Function to get *Data1* in row two:

```
=INDEX(Label1,1,1)
```

To return *Data2* in your example

```
=INDEX(Label1,1,2)
```

**Edit1:** This is VBA equivalent

```
Range("Label1")(1) '~~> return Data1
Range("Label1")(2) '~~> return Data2
```

Or you can be explicit

```
Range("Label1").Item(1, 1) '~~> return Data1
```

Here's VBA using *WorsheetFunction*

```
WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Label1"), 1, 1) '~~> return Data1
```

Comment: That is helpful, but INDEX won't work in VBA, at least not as defined. I have tried everything up to this: `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() Dim bar As String Dim foo As Integer For foo = 1 To 5 bar = "space" & foo Cells(foo, 4).Value = Worksheets(Sheet6).WorksheetFunction.Index(bar, 1, 1) Next End Sub` And had no luck. How do I get the worksheet function to work in VBA?